# Why Visual Studio is warning me of "Derefencing NULL pointer" when I want to check a struct allocation?

Tags: c, malloc

Say I have a random struct, for example, a chess position.

```
typedef char chessPos[2];
```

and I have linked list of chess positions.

```
typedef struct _chessPosCell
{
    chessPos position;
    struct _chessPosCell* next;
} chessPosCell;
```

Now, I want to create a new pointer to a list. so I use the following:

```
chessPosCell* answer = (chessPosCell*)malloc(sizeof(chessPosCell));
```

Now, I want to check if the memory has been allocated correctly.
So I want to create a specific function to check EVERY allocation in my code.

```
void checkAllocation(void* ptr)

    {
        if (ptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory allocation failure. \n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

My question is, how do I send my new allocated memory?

1.

```
checkAllocation(&answer);
```

2. 

```
checkAllocation(answer);
```

(The difference is just the '&')

I'm asking this because I've been discussing with a friend. I'm using option 1, because option 2 gives me Visual Studio warning of "Derefencing NULL pointer "answer".
And the friend says I need to use option 2, because I want to check "answer" allocation, and not it's address allocation. However, option 2 gives me the warning mentioned above!

So I've been a bit confused. Can anyone please explain this part to me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `checkAllocation(answer);`.

The definition `chessPosCell* answer = (chessPosCell*)malloc(sizeof(chessPosCell));` calls `malloc` to reserve some memory. `malloc` returns the address of that memory (or a null pointer). The definition initializes the value of `answer` to have that address.

`checkAllocation(&answer);` would pass the address of the object named `answer` to `checkAllocation`. `chessAllocation(answer)` passes the value of the object named `answer` to `checkAllocation`. It is the value of `answer` that is the address return by `malloc`, and that is what you want to check.

Incidentally, the definition is better written as `chessPosCell *answer =  malloc(sizeof *answer));`:

- By using `sizeof *answer` instead of `sizeof(chessPosCell)`, you get the size of the type being pointed to. This will remain correct even if the type of `answer` is later changed in code edits.
- C automatically converts from `void *` to other pointer-to-object types, so the cast to `(chessPosCell*)` is unnecessary. And sometimes using a cast can suppress a warning message about a bug, because compilers assume that casts are intentional, that they indicate the author knows what they are doing.

Comment: OP uses VS and this program compiles by default as C++ - thus casts

Answer (score 2):

1. If you use Visual Studio and write in C language (not C++ which is default) change in project properties language used:

[image]

Then you will not need (and you should not) to cast pointers.

> (The difference is just the '&')

The `&` gives the reference (address) of the object.

```
int *pointer = malloc(sizeof(*pointer));
```

Defines the variable `pointer` having type `pointer to int` and initializes it with the value returned by the function malloc.

If you want to hack if the stored value is NULL you want to use this variable

```
if(pointer == NULL)
```

When you add the `&` you get the reference (address) of the variable `pointer` not the value stored in this variable.

Same is with other types.

```
int i = 5;

if(i == 5)
```

`&i` will give the reference of the variable `i` not the value stored in this variable.